# Solve $23x \equiv 1 \mod 120$ using Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving, euclidean-algorithm

I want to do inverse modulo to solve the equation

$$23x \equiv 1 \mod 120$$

And to do that I used the extended Euclidean Algorithm. 
$$120=23\times5+5$$
$$23=5 \times4+3$$
$$5=3\times1+2$$
$$3=2\times1+1$$
Which makes $1 \equiv3-2\times1=3-2$. I then substituted the other values to get the following

---

$$2=5-3\times1=5-3$$
$$1=3-(5-3)$$

---

$$3=23-5\times4$$
$$1=(23-5\times4)-(5-(23-5\times4))$$

---

$$5 \equiv120-23 \times5$$
$$1 \equiv (23-((120-23\times5)\times4)-(120-23\times5(23-((120-23\times5)\times4))$$

---

But now I'm not sure how much I need to simplify this down in order to find the answer.

Comment: Well, to construct an explicit inverse you need to find integers $a,b$ with $120a+23b=1$, or at least you need to find $b$.  Note:  you can simplify the original problem by noting that $120=2^3\times 3\times 5$ and solving for each factor separately, then using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We wish to solve the congruence $23x \equiv 1 \pmod{120}$.

You correctly obtained 
\begin{align*}
120 & = 5 \cdot 23 + 5\\
23 & = 4 \cdot 5 + 3\\
5 & = 1 \cdot 3 + 2\\
3 & = 1 \cdot 2 + 1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Now, if we work backwards, we can obtain $1$ as a linear combination of $23$ and $120$.
\begin{align*}
1 & = 3 - 2\\
  & = 3 - (5 - 3)\\
  & = 2 \cdot 3  - 5\\
  & = 2(23 - 4 \cdot 5) - 5\\
  & = 2 \cdot 23 - 9 \cdot 5\\
  & = 2 \cdot 23 - 9 \cdot (120 - 5 \cdot 23)\\
  & = 47 \cdot 23 - 9 \cdot 120
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$23 \cdot 47 \equiv 1 \pmod{120}$$
Hence, $x \equiv 47 \pmod{120}$, so $47$ is the multiplicative inverse of $23$ modulo $120$.

Comment: That’s the exact answe I was looking for! $9 \cdot 120$ is made equal to $0$ the iggy?

Comment: Any integer multiple of $120$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $120$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to save you calculating backwards:
$$\begin{array}{rrrl}
r_i &u_i&v_i&q_i \\
\hline
120&0&1\\
23&1&0&5\\
\hline
5&-5& 1&4 \\
3&21&-4&1 \\
2&-26&5&1\\
1&\color{red}{47}& -9\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
whence the *Bézout's relation*:
$$47\cdot 23-9\cdot120=1$$
which says the inverse of $23$ mod. $120$ is $47$.